# Restful POST method has JSONObject always empty

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, netbeans-8

I have this dev environment:

- NetBeans: 8.1
- Glassfish: 4.1
- Java 8.1

and my application is made of a jar and a war.

My Web Service is in the jar file and it is like this:

```
@Path("/messages")
@Stateless
public class MessagesWebService extends AbstractWebService {

   ....

   @POST
   @Path("/send")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String sendMessage(JSONObject messageParams) {

       System.out.println(messageParams);
       ....
   }
}
```

My war file contains:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("ws")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
         Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();        
         addRestResourceClasses(resources);            
         return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(webServices.MessagesWebService.class);
        resources.add(webServices.SessionsWebService.class);  
    }
}
```

Others services work as expected and returns json data. The sendMessage, instead, always receives an empty messageParams({}).

This is from my Java Client:

```
....
URL obj = new URL(baseUrl + path + urlParameters);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
....
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);                                    
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
msg.put("mbxId", 4l);
msg.put("subject", "Just A Test");

osw.write(msg.toString());
osw.flush();
osw.close();    
os.close();
```

Please, help me to sort this out!

Comment: might you be missing @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) in the post method?

Comment: @Produces should be for the response format. Anyway nothing changes adding it. Thk

Comment: Does @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) works for other services as you mentioned ?

Comment: To be precise, others methods have @QueryParam("mbxId").... and @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). Not @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON). I apologize for the misleading info.